# How to move Dropbox "Camera Uploads"?

Tags: dropbox

I am a fan of Dropbox's new automatic camera uploads feature. However, I am not so keen on the name of the directory itself. Is there a way for me to rename "Camera Uploads" to something else?

Simply renaming the directory will cause Dropbox to regenerate it the next time a camera is connected, and I cannot find anything in the local preferences or on the website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of today (6/10/2012) there is not a way to do this. Changing my folder name to `Camera` from `Camera Uploads` prompted the upload process to create a new folder named `Camera Uploads`. You can rename any folder to `Camera Uploads` (top level only) and it will upload photos into it automatically.

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand on Dez's answer, whilst you may not be able to change the directory that the photos are uploaded to originally, you are able to move the photos into different directories, or have directories within the `Camera Uploads` folder, meaning that you are still able to organise the photos as you wish. Once uploaded, according to the dropbox website:

> Camera Upload tries to be smart about not uploading the same photos and videos more than once. It will not re-upload these files even if you move, rename, or delete them from the Camera Uploads folder.

Checkout [Where are my Camera Uploads?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/288/en) on the Dropbox Help Site for further details