# Are there any automation tools that organize your uploaded photos in Dropbox?

Tags: photos, dropbox, upload, trello-organization, automation

This is sort of a followup or corollary question to this:
[How to move Dropbox "Camera Uploads"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/how-to-move-dropbox-camera-uploads)

Are there any third party apps or simple automation tools/scripts that help you organize (and maybe auto-tag) your photos once they are uploaded to the Camera Uploads folder?